# помощь с ЧПУ в yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2, .htaccess, apache2, чпу

Знаю что тема обсуждалась миллион раз, я сам перелопатил кучу мануалов, но результатов ноль.Стоит ubuntu 16.04 Apache2(modrewrite включен) php 7.0 .
Думаю начать надо с конфигурации виртуального хоста:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yii2.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/yii2.com

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
 </VirtualHost>

 # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Далее было перепробованно куча вариантов с .htaccess. ничего не помогло, пробовал варианты с разными поддоменами(слышал что такой вариант не реализовать на хостинге, так что лучше без него).Проконсультируйте пажалст что куда конкретно.два дня уже убил, не хочу третий сидеть(

Answer (score 0):

Проверял конфигурацию самого приложения Yii2?
frontend/config/main.php
секция components, должно быть что-то вроде:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => []
],
```

Comment: все верно.urlmanager раскоментировал.значение параметров как у Вас в примере

Comment: но результат такой же

Comment: @Dmitrij, можно немного более подробно о проблеме, какого вида получаются URL? И что указано в .htaccess? А еще читает ли сам веб-сервер на хостинге конфигурацию htaccess?

Comment: url на стартовую страницу frontend выглядит: http://yii2.com/frontend/web/

Comment: index.php удалось убрать в url manager.

Comment: mod_rewrite включен если вы об этом. На данный момент все htaccess удалил.